# Vue.js | ReferenceError: Model property is undefined on input change

Tags: vue.js

The following Vue.js v3 component file :

```
// src/components/Unlock.vue

<script setup>
  import axios from 'axios'
</script>

<script>

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        username:'',
        hash: ''
      }
    },

    methods: {
      unlock() {
        let username = this.username ? this.username.trim() : ''
        let hash = this.hash ? this.hash.trim() : ''
        if (username.length && hash.length) {
          axios.post('/unlock', { username, hash }).then(({ data }) => {
            this.$router.push(`/unlocked/${data.index}`)
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="username"
           type="text"
           placeholder="username">
    <br>
    <input v-model="hash"
           type="text"
           placeholder="redeem code">
    <br>
    <button type="button" @click="unlock">CLICK HERE TO UNLOCK</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Is throwing the following **Errors** whenever I start typing in any of the two inputs:

```
index.e65df20f.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.s.onUpdate:modelValue.a.<computed>.a.<computed> [as _assign] (index.e65df20f.js:1:3237)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (vendor.7ec322db.js:1:53128)
```

and

```
index.e65df20f.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: hash is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.s.onUpdate:modelValue.a.<computed>.a.<computed> [as _assign] (index.e65df20f.js:1:3237)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (vendor.7ec322db.js:1:53128)
```

But I cannot spot what I'm doing wrong


You can replicate the problem on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-frog-i74mhd)


**Remember** to open **your browser's console** to see the errors as soon as you start typing in any of the inputs. They will not show up on the "console" of the sandbox GUI.

Comment: As @tao indicated to me in chat, the problem was due to the fact that I was using 2 <script> tags. If include all of my Js in 1 <script> tag in this particular view, the problem is gone. I don't know if this is the complete answer as I have other views with 2 <script> tags (but without user inputs) that don't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do not instantiate reactive properties (e.g: `username`, `hash`) with `undefined`.

Instantiate with `null` (or whatever falsey value makes sense for that prop: empty array, `0`, empty string, etc...).

In the above case, both reactive props should be instantiated with empty string:

```
data: () => ({
  username: '',
  hash: ''
})
```

If you instantiate with `undefined`, it's exactly as if you didn't declare it at all. Hence, your current error: you haven't actually declared either `username` or `hash`.

---

If you're using TypeScript, it's a very good idea to replace

```
export default {...}
```

with

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({...})
```

Comment: Your solution works but I don't understand why. I have another component file, where I don't need to `import { defineComponent }...` and where I also use `data { .. }` and it works with no errors (granted there are no `input`s on that component). Also, the Vue 3 docs do not mention having to `import { defineComponent }`: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#defining-a-component

Comment: @Sprout, you don't need `defineComponent` in SFC's if you don't use TS. It adds type inference. But you must instantiate reactive props with something else than `undefined`. That's your "real" error.

Comment: Setting props to `undefined` works fine, as long as I use `defineComponent`. When I remove `defineComponent`, regardless of whether I use `''` or `undefined` I start getting the error again. I'm not using TS, so I don't know what's happening.

Comment: I think my project is set to use Typescript just because I've installed vite I guess ? Even thought I'm not explicitly using Typescript anywhere in my code.. Do you know how can I completely disable Typscript ?

Comment: @Sprout, no, Vite and TS work independently. If your `main` is `.js`, and you don't have a `tsconfig.json`, you're probably not using TS. If you want me to look further into this and tell you exactly what's the cause, I'd need to be able to repro. I suggest using codesandbox.io or similar, as it allows you to repro your configuration/files exactly. Also, I'm surprised to find out instantiating a reactive prop with `undefined` works. I'm fairly certain this wasn't the case a few versions back. Not sure about Vue3, but it definitely didn't work in Vue2.

Comment: I managed to replicate the Error on codesandbox. You can see it here: codesandbox.io/s/purple-frog-i74mhd.

Comment: @Sprout, the only tag you can have more than one of in an SFC is `<style>`. Once I remove one of the `<script>` tags, [all works well](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-lederberg-sc31wn), including instantiating `hash` and `username` with `undefined` which is new to me (it didn't use to work). The idea behind an SFC is that it has only one default export. A `<script setup>` already has an `export default`. Under the hood, it wraps everything in an `export default defineComponent({ setup() { /* your content here */ }})`. So you basically had two default exports from 1 SFC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243101/discussion-between-tao-and-sprout-coder).

Comment: I'm not using TypeScript, was getting this exact error, and it's resolved by switching to this export syntax.

I only started getting this error after I added a very simple <script setup> section:

<script setup>
import { Download } from '@element-plus/icons-vue'
</script>
I'm not clear on why the alternate export syntax resolved it, but maybe this is useful info to whoever comes across this next.